# Python 3: Selenium & geckodriver error?

Tags: python, selenium

I have written a basic script which tries to open a website with Selenium(webdriver).

Here is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")

driver.quit()
```

When I launch the above script the Firefox browser pops-up, however it remains blank and it does not navigate to the mentioned website(in this case Google)? I do get an error on terminal screen:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 10, in
>   
>       driver = webdriver.Firefox()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
>   line 158, in **init**
>       keep_alive=True)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 154, in **init**
>       self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 243, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 311, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 237, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection
>   refused

Here is the geckodriver log file contents:

> 1513507080726 geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
>   1513507080735 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:47815
>   1513507081261 mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command:
>   "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile"
>   "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.IaZFxa8B0Ir8"
>   1513507085202 Marionette  ERROR   Error on starting server: [Exception...
>   "Component returned failure code: 0x804b0036
>   (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE)
>   [nsIServerSocket.initSpecialConnection]"  nsresult: "0x804b0036
>   (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   chrome://marionette/content/server.js ::
>   MarionetteServer.prototype.start :: line 95"  data: no] [Exception...
>   "Component returned failure code: 0x804b0036
>   (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE)
>   [nsIServerSocket.initSpecialConnection]"  nsresult: "0x804b0036
>   (NS_ERROR_SOCKET_ADDRESS_IN_USE)"  location: "JS frame ::
>   chrome://marionette/content/server.js ::
>   MarionetteServer.prototype.start :: line 95"  data: no]
>   MarionetteServer.prototype.start@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:95:19
>   MarionetteComponent.prototype.init@resource://gre/components/marionette.js:217:5
>   MarionetteComponent.prototype.handle@resource://gre/components/marionette.js:112:5

I have no idea what is going on here, I can't seem to figure out how to fix this error? Do you guys have any idea, how this error can be fixed and what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **`geckodriver 0.19.1`** use the latest **`Selenium v3.8.1`** along with latest **`Firefox Quantum`** Web Browser.

Finally, when you initialize the `webdriver`, instead of `driver = webdriver.Firefox()` try with :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/path/to/geckodriver")
```

Comment: Hmmmm... I thougt I had downloaded the latest Selenium version available? I did a pip3 install selenium? Alright, I will check. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like I have the latest version for Selenium(ver. 3.8.0), I can't get the  version 3.8.1 through pip? Anyway I have also tried to write the executable path, but unfortunately I get the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Browser and its selenium driver must be matched in version.

Refer to [geckodriver release](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) page to get the right release of driver you want. [Chrome webdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) is also a good choice.

The exception `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused`
 is usually caused by driver mismatch with the browser.